# Need to remove the exact group of characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g, regexp-substr

I need to remove all the characters after a particular string (**-->**).

```
select 
      REGEXP_SUBSTR('-->Team Name - Red-->blue', '[^(-->)]+') 
from dual;
```

expected result from the above query is "**Team Name - Red**". But its returning "**Team Name**".

Its filtering out everything whenever it matches any of one character.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `Regexp_Substr()` analytic function :

```
Select Regexp_Substr('-->Team Name - Red-->blue', 
                     '-{2}>(.*?)-{2}>',1,1,null,1) as "Result"
  From dual;

Result
---------------
Team Name - Red
```

`-{2}>` ~ exactly twice occurence of `-` and single occurence of `>` e.g. ( `-->` )

`(.*?)` ~ matches anything delimited by the pattern above

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=86867e3aa3a2ac6bedbfcfcd44a082e4)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Is there anyway that I can exclude exact group of characters like "-->"
in my query, I'm actually using as below 
`REGEXP_SUBSTR( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( MNEMONIC, '-->' ), '[^(-->)]+' ) AS parent_Name`

So the mnemonic column will be aggregated with the -->.

Comment: you're welcome @SharathTanish . Waht did you get when you tried in that manner?

Comment: your suggestion is working fantastic for this situation @Barbaros Özhan. But, when there is a situation where there is `->` is exist in data, that trims off the required data as well. 
for ex:
`Select Regexp_Substr('-->Team Name - Red->01 --> Team Name - blue->02 --> Team Name - orange->03', '[^>]+[^[:punct:]]') as "Result" From dual;` 
in this case, expected is `Team Name - Red->01` but it returns `Team Name - Red`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here with a capture group:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE('-->Team Name - Red-->blue', '.*-->(.*?)-->.*', '\1')
FROM dual;
```

The output from this is `Team Name - Red`

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the response @Tim Biegeleisen, But I want to achieve this using REGEXP_SUBSTR

Comment: @SharathTanish What is your aversion to using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`?  I mean, we _could_ just use base string functions like `INSTR`, but it would require more code, and be uglier than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you, actually, want to return string between two `-->` marks. A *good, old* `substr` + `instr` option would be

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '-->Team Name - Red-->blue' from dual)
  3  select substr(col,
  4                instr(col, '-->', 1, 1) + 3,
  5                instr(col, '-->', 1, 2) - instr(col, '-->', 1, 1) - 3
  6               ) result
  7  from test;

RESULT
---------------
Team Name - Red

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Littlefoot, But I want to achieve this using REGEXP_SUBSTR

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this will probably perform MUCH faster (than regular expressions) if you're dealing with a large data set.